# Using Regex in Python to Extract Times from Email Text

Tags: python

I have the email content. From this content I then want to extract any times that exist. The times are in 24 hour format, contain a colon separator (eg 13:00) and can appear anywhere in the text.

As an example:

```
"Some text some text some text 12:00 Some text some text some text"
```

When I use this line to extract the time, the result is blank:

```
tp_time = re.findall(r'(^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$)', tp_msg)
print(tp_time)
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The times "are in 24 hour format" but `[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]` will not match e.g. `17:00`. What's going on?

Comment: Should have used `(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?*

You are looking for `r'(^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$)'`

`^` denotes start of line or start of string (depending on mode)

`$` denotes end of line or end of string (depending on mode)

You should use `\b` instead of `^` and `\b` instead of `$`, i.e.

```
import re
text = "Some text some text some text 12:00 Some text some text some text"
print(re.findall(r'(\b[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]\b)', text))
```

output

```
['12:00']
```

If you want to know more about `\b` read [python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: @MikeM `re.findall` returns a _list_ of found text. The brackets in the output is the result of printing a list. Which, in this situation, happens to contain only 1 item.

Comment: @MikeM oh, you mean the opening & closing parentheses? Beats me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]` instead of `(^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$)`

Comment: How will that ever match, say, `23:15`?

Comment: @pepoluan  Above regex is used for 12 hours format, so with 24 hours format, please use ```([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]```